# Android App recorder for certain tasks

Tags: android, time-management

Basically, I am looking for an Android app that every day (or possibly in other intervals) offers me the option to "check", that I did something, like for instance taking medication. This is because I sometimes forget, whether I actually did something important or not, especially if it is easy to do. At a later time, I should then be able to look at something like a calendar, which shows the days I did said task.

It would be great if the app could handle multiple tasks simultaneously. Another useful but not necessary feature would be  specifying how much I did something (like how often or for how long) and displaying statistics for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Amazingly, just 1h after having seen your question I've noticed this app at F-Droid. Didn't try it myself, but looks like what you want:</sup>

**[Loop - Habit Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.isoron.uhabits)** seems to fit your needs:

> Loop helps you create and maintain good habits, allowing you to achieve your long-term goals. Detailed graphs and statistics show you how your habits improved over time. It is completely ad-free and open source.

[image: Loop] [image: Loop] [image: Loop]
<sup>*Loop* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.isoron.uhabits); click images for larger variants)</sup>

So *how* does it meet your requirements?

- **offers me the option to "check", that I did something:** Yes. And it's you to define the "somethings".
- **something like a calendar, which shows the days I did said task:** Check, it's there.
- **handle multiple tasks simultaneously:** pretty much looks like, yes.
- **displaying statistics for this task:** that too, yes.

As initially mentioned, *Loop* is also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.isoron.uhabits). It's free and open source.

Comment: Excellent! This seems to work like a charm.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the feedback as well!